# StreamBuilder - Bad state: Use multiple StreamBuilder on one screen

Tags: flutter, dart, stream, stream-builder

Since I use multiple StreamBuilder in my screen I get a Bad state error.
I know that I have to use a StreamController and use it with .broadcast().

Because I dont create the streams by myself I dont know how to change the controller of these streams.

This is my code:

```
class MyScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyScreenState createState() => _MyScreenState();
}

class _MyScreenState extends State<MyScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: [
            StreamBuilder<List<int>>(
                stream: streamOne?.value,
                builder: (c, snapshot) {
                  final newValueOne = snapshot.data;
                  return Text(newValueOne);
                }),
            StreamBuilder<List<int>>(
                stream: streamTwo?.value,
                builder: (c, snapshot) {
                  final newValueTwo = snapshot.data;
                  return Text(newValueTwo);
                }),
            StreamBuilder<List<int>>(
                stream: streamThree?.value,
                builder: (c, snapshot) {
                  final newValueThree = snapshot.data;
                  return Text(newValueThree);
                }),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried to have it as BroadcastStreams:

```
class MyScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyScreenState createState() => _MyScreenState();
}

class _MyScreenState extends State<MyScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: [
            StreamBuilder<List<int>>(
                stream: streamOne?.asBroadcastStream(),
                builder: (c, snapshot) {
                  final newValueOne = snapshot.data;
                  return Text(newValueOne);
                }),
            StreamBuilder<List<int>>(
                stream: streamTwo?.asBroadcastStream(),
                builder: (c, snapshot) {
                  final newValueTwo = snapshot.data;
                  return Text(newValueTwo);
                }),
            StreamBuilder<List<int>>(
                stream: streamThree?.asBroadcastStream(),
                builder: (c, snapshot) {
                  final newValueThree = snapshot.data;
                  return Text(newValueThree);
                }),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This didnt work and gave me still a bad state error.

Would be great if somone could help me here.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your streamBuilder builder, you have to check that the snapshot has actually received the data, otherwise your Text widget is receiving null, thus, throwing a bad state error:

```
 StreamBuilder<List<int>>(
                stream: streamThree.asBroadcastStream(),
                builder: (c, snapshot) {
                  if(snapshot.hasData){
                    final newValueThree = snapshot.data;
                    return Text(newValueThree);
                  } else {
                    // return any other widget like CircularProgressIndicator
                  }
                }),
```

You can also check on

```dart
snpashot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done
```

and

```dart
snpashot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active
```

and

```dart
snpashot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Arnaud Delubac. I also had to check if the array I get from the stream is not empty:

```
StreamBuilder<List<int>>(
    stream: streamThree.asBroadcastStream(),
    builder: (c, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data.isNotEmpty && snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
        final newValueThree = snapshot.data;
        return Text(newValueThree);
      } else {
        // return any other widget like CircularProgressIndicator
      }
    }),
```